# Serving an IIS website through nginx (proxy_pass) doesn't display CSS, images or js (404 not found)

Tags: nginx, iis, reverse-proxy

I have an nginx reverse proxy running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When requests are made to the nginx proxy, it passes it to an IIS server containing one (default) website. It seems to render the HTML fine, but unfortunately the server responds with a 404 error for all of the other assets.

Here is the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Here is my `default` nginx server config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://104.46.52.226/;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Here's the result of the request to `example.com` or `www.example.com` (the hosts file **has** been changed):

[image]

I figured perhaps it was an issue with the fact there's no `root` directive in my server config - but then I didn't really know where to start with that issue. At the very least I know it isn't an issue with the IIS server itself, because I can browse the localhost perfectly.

Any thoughts? Thanks very much in advance.

Edit: Here are my error logs, too:

```
2015/10/13 09:41:10 [emerg] 3069#0: invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/armari.com:31
2015/10/13 10:12:33 [emerg] 3606#0: "listen" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/armari.com:2
2015/10/13 13:39:18 [error] 3911#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/css/new-web.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.39.188.214, server: armari.com, request: "GET /css/new-web.css HTTP/1.1", host: "www.armari.com", referrer: "http://www.armari.com/"
2015/10/13 13:39:18 [error] 3911#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/css/nivo/themes/default/default.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.39.188.214, server: armari.com, request: "GET /css/nivo/themes/default/default.css HTTP/1.1", host: "www.armari.com", referrer: "http://www.armari.com/"
2015/10/13 13:39:18 [error] 3911#0: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/css/nivo/nivo-slider.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.39.188.214, server: armari.com, request: "GET /css/nivo/nivo-slider.css HTTP/1.1", host: "www.armari.com", referrer: "http://www.armari.com/"
2015/10/13 13:39:21 [error] 3911#0: *8 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/css/new-web.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.39.188.214, server: armari.com, request: "GET /css/new-web.css HTTP/1.1", host: "armari.com", referrer: "http://armari.com/"
2015/10/13 13:39:21 [error] 3909#0: *10 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/css/nivo/themes/default/default.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.39.188.214, server: armari.com, request: "GET /css/nivo/themes/default/default.css HTTP/1.1", host: "armari.com", referrer: "http://armari.com/"
2015/10/13 13:39:21 [error] 3909#0: *11 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/css/nivo/nivo-slider.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.39.188.214, server: armari.com, request: "GET /css/nivo/nivo-slider.css HTTP/1.1", host: "armari.com", referrer: "http://armari.com/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution in the end - I was forcing the nginx server to attempt serving files locally using the `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`. All I had to do was remove this line and it works perfectly :)

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://104.46.52.226/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the least likely problem, is 80 the correct port for `proxy_pass http://104.46.52.226/`? If not, which port is this listening on? If it's, say, 5000, you need proxy_pass http://104.46.52.226:5000; This probably isn't your issue.

You need to set some headers in the location block so that IIS can use them:

```
    proxy_set_header  x-real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  x-forwarded-for  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  host             $http_host;
```

To quote [Karl Seguin](http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2010/01/13/asp-net-performance-part-5-nginx/):

> Since Nginx is actually issueing the request to our web server, we are
>   adding headers to the request so that the web server has all necessary
>   informaton.

He also talks about caching.

File `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/armari.com` looks like it has a commented out `server {` line. That's one of the errors. ALL the files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` need to be working for Nginx to feel good. If that's this file, you probably just didn't paste the `#` (comment start code). Or perhaps you changed it since the error happened.

Comment: Thanks very much Palu, but thankfully I figured out the issue - I was trying to serve local files with that `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` line; whoops!